# ! Package undolabl Error: Label `pagesLTS.roman.local' shall be overridden

Tags: bibtex, biber, makeindex

I am facing following problem:

After compiling or indexing my document with different compiler (`BibTex`, `Biber`, `Makeindex`) `PDFLaTeX` doesn't compile anymore and throws following error:

```
! Package undolabl Error: Label `pagesLTS.roman.local' shall be overridden
```

The same error I've got by making index for a nomenclature file.

For example, for generating bibliography chapter I am able to compile two times with `PDFLaTeX`, then with `BibTex` or `Biber` and then while compiling for the forth time with `PDFLaTeX` I receive the error message.

Does anybody have an idea what it could be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any chance you can come up with a small example document that reproduces the issue (what we call an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? Without any code to reproduce what you are seeing it is extremely hard to give any useful advice.

Comment: @moewe, Thank you for the reply, but I think I've figured out what the problem was. At least for the `BibTex` case.
I was using following acronym package `\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}` to generate a list of acronyms, and after removing this line and using for example this alternative `\usepackage{glossaries}` instead, the error disapears.

Comment: If you found the culprit yourself, please post a self-answer and accept it. In its current form the question cannot be answered by anyone other than you, since we need to see the code that reproduces these issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve the isue, it helped me to remove following acronym package `\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}` I was using. In my case I was able to use `BibTex` and `Makeindex` compilers with no problem.

As an alternative to `acronym` package, one can use the `glossaries` package.